# sed replacement for no_proxy cuts number in localhost

Tags: bash, sed

I have a no_proxy string I'd like to modify to fit with Java Opts.

```
❯ export no_proxy_test=localhost,127.0.0.1,.myfancy.domain,.myotherfancy.domain
❯ echo $no_proxy_test
localhost,127.0.0.1,.myfancy.domain,.myotherfancy.domain
```

I need for each value to be delimited with pipes "|" instead and I need to remove the dots for the wildcard. So should be:

```
localhost|127.0.0.1|myfancy.domain|myotherfancy.domain
```

When I use:

```
❯ echo $no_proxy_test | sed 's/,./|/g'
localhost|27.0.0.1|myfancy.domain|myotherfancy.domain
```

For some reason it cuts the 1 in 127.0.0.1 and I don't understand why? I thought I may achieve it with a double sed:

```
❯ echo $no_proxy_test | sed 's/,/|/g' | sed 's/|./|/g'
localhost|27.0.0.1|myfancy.domain|myotherfancy.domain
```

But same problem there. Does anyone have an idea? I don't want to sed replace 27 with 127. Would be interesting if I ran into a bug or if anyone could explain why 1 is being cut from the string.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```bash
sed -E 's/,\.?/|/g'    # POSIX ERE
sed 's/,\.\{0,1\}/|/g' # POSIX BRE
```

This will replace a comma followed with an optional `.` char with a pipe symbol.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/7lnEQh):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='localhost,127.0.0.1,.myfancy.domain,.myotherfancy.domain'
sed 's/,\.\{0,1\}/|/g' <<< "$s"
# => localhost|127.0.0.1|myfancy.domain|myotherfancy.domain
```

Comment: Thank you! Have you got any clue why it's cutting the 1 in 127 when I just use ",." to replace with sed? Seems like a bug to me?

Comment: @lema [It does not](https://ideone.com/7lnEQh) cut anything. If you have some other output, then 1) it is a bug on your end, or 2) you are using a different code and something happens before this sed operation.

Comment: I got that thank you, what I meant was why my example I started the thread with cuts the 1 in 127. See: https://ideone.com/DAEdxn
Have you got any idea?

Comment: @lema `.` matches and consumes any char. The `,.` matches `,#`, `,1`, `,A`, `,l` etc.